# HBase Table design - Tall-narrow vs Flat-wide approach

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have to store information regarding an entity monthly in a HBase table.I want to process all the month details available so far for entities using mapreduce logic.I'm confused whether to opt for tall-narrow or flat wide design for HBase table.

Using flat wide approach , entity Id will be kept as row key and month id as column qualifier and details as qualifiers value.In HBase-mapreduce,I can fetch all details for an entity in map and process.

Tall-narrow approach will be storing row key as combination of entity id and month. Also the details will be stored in a seperate column.In HBase -mapreduce ,I have to fetch details for entiy in map and aggregate for all months in reducer.

Which approach is better and yield better performance ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you have to store the information once in a month??Also, hoe much?

Comment: Information granulity is monthly.It can happen that particular monthly information for an entity can be updated frequenlty.Also information to be stored consists of 500 key-values.There could be millions of such entities.I have no exact figure for the volume of data.

Answer (score 3):

A few assumptions:

- You have many entities and you wish to save their state once every month
- The result you want from the MapReduce job aggregates over these entities and saves information based on the month. e.g. What the numbers were (across all entities) in Jan 2013.
- You are not storing a HUGE amount of information per entity per month

I think the `Flat-Wide` table approach would yield better results.

Designing a flat and wide table would mean all your entity data stays together in the row (that's why it's important the size isn't huge. If I recall correctly HBase stores data in blocks per column family basis and this is the level over which compaction occurs .. more info under [Suggestions on performance optimization section](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/io/hfile/HFile.html)). Since its all together you should be able to just fetch any entities information quickly given that you have the rowkey-column family-column quantifier information. Also assuming the entity identifiers are either hashed (or you prefix them with a hash) you should be able  to prevent [monotonically increasing](http://ikaisays.com/2011/01/25/app-engine-datastore-tip-monotonically-increasing-values-are-bad/) key values as well.

Regarding running the MapReduce Job. Since your data is distributed evenly across all region servers at this point, your computation will be distributed as well. Meaning all machine are equally likely to be doing equal amount of work. However you could get that with a `Tall-Narrow` model as well (assuming you designed the schema correctly).